# Pytest Mocker dynamically created instance

Tags: python, pytest

I am writing a unit test that verifies when a method from an instance of a class throws a `ValueError` or `KeyError` a certain event is raised.

Usually when I do this for regular methods, I do a

```
mocker.patch('module.method',side_effect=ValueError())
```

and that works fine.  But this is not working for a class that I generate.

The code for generation is something like this:

```
provider = clients.get_provider(provider_name)
try:
  provider.generate_relationships()
except (ValueError, KeyError) as e:
  raise RelationshipGenerationError(e)
```

In this, clients is an instance that is a global variable that contains an array of provider instances.  the `get_provider` method, returns a provider instance from the clients array of instances.

I've tried a few different things most are trying to do the same thing though:

1. creating a fixture that returns an instance of a class, injecting that fixture into my unit test, and then using `mocker.patch.object(provider, 'generate_relationships', side_effect=ValueError)`
2. fixture injection, `provider.generate_relationships = MagicMock(side_effect=ValueError())`
3. This:

   ```
   with mocker.patch("module.provider", return_value=provider_instance_fixture):
       with pytest.raises(RelationshipGenerationError):
           generate_relationships()
   ```

I'm expecting the code `provider.generate_relationships()` to throw a `ValueError` but the method gets executed. MrBean Bremen
made a comment that I think is correct. Because my code generates that provider globally before this particular code gets executed, the mock cant patch it because it already exists.

Is there a force pytest to treat any instance of `Provider` as a mocked instance?

Comment: Are you saying that `provider` is a global variable in your module? If that is the case, and the code get's already executed while importing your module, patching will just be too late. You may add a few details about how your code is organized and how you import the modules, otherwise it is difficult to understand what exactly are you trying to do.

Comment: @MrBeanBremen - ahh, yes I think thats whats happening.  the get_provider method returns an instance that is already created globally.  It doesn't instantiate new instance.  Is there a way to handle this situation in a test?

Comment: The better solution would be to refactor the code to not run the code in the global scope (e.g. move the code into a function, and call it after the usual `if __name__ == "__main__"` check). If you can't do that, you can reload the tested module in the test (`importlib.reload()`), though it would still be executed on loading it the first time before the test.

Comment: This is if you need to patch something in that module -otherwise you could just make sure to only import the module inside the test (which is also fragile though).

Comment: Yeah, at the current time, I cant refactor.  I'm taking over a much larger codebase and needed to put in a requirement.  But I intend to refactor eventually so that it's not global.  I think I will go with importing in the test for now just to ensure code coverage is there.